# Good introduction to (pseudo) random number generation

Tags: c, algorithm, random, probability

I am extremely new to the concept of random number generation and I need to create my own algorithm for work written in C (the built-in random number generator will not work for me).

Can somebody point me to a good introduction on the topic so that I may be able to grasp the concept? Everything I've found so far seems to explain itself in terms of itself and it's not very helpful.

I'm looking for a layman's explanation on the topic.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator ?

Comment: It may be useful for you to explain why C's generator won't work for you. Otherwise, answerers may unknowingly suggest algorithms that have the same "won't work for you" problem.

Comment: Because this is for an embedded C application. Different compilers use different algorithms for doing this; there is no "standard" algorithm for different compilers, just a requirement that such a function exists. Further, since this is for an embedded application, I need to be able to optimize speed and memory; without understanding how they work, I can't really do that.

Answer (score 1):

Read chapter 7 in the online [Numerical Recipes in C](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

For a good place to start learning, the Wikipedia articles are pretty good, and much more up-to-date than, say, Knuth. Also check out [this paper](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.jones/GoodPracticeRNG.pdf) by David Jones.

If C's isn't good enough for you, also consider an external library like my own public domain [ojrandlib](http://github.com/lcrocker/ojrandlib), which gives you a choice of algorithms like Marsaglia's MWC, Mersenne Twister, and others.

Comment: my supervisor suggested I look at the Tiny Mersenne Twister (http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html). That's probably what I'll end up going with, but again, I hate using code I have no understanding of. As an intern, this stuff is way above my head at the moment.

Comment: Personally, I think MT is a bit overrated, but I included it as an option in my library because it's popular. I personally prefer Jones's JKISS when I want the best statistical properties, or MWC for speed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to look into that one.

Comment: Regarding Wikipedia, my main problem is that the articles (or anything else I've found online for that matter) don't really define terminology well. I haven't even taken a probability course; the internship description only asked for experience in embedded C/C++ and assembly. So I've got a lot of learning to do.

Answer (score 0):

The first half of Knuth's TAOCP volume 2 ("Seminumerical algorithms") is devoted to random-number generation.  He talks about a few pseudo-random number generators, then he spends a long time talking about what properties make a "good" PRNG for most purposes.  It's probably worth reading if your job is to produce a PRNG that doesn't suck.

You might also want to look at George Marsaglia's work.

Comment: Pierre L'Ecuyer is also worth looking at.  http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/papers.html